# Find value in calculated rnk colum, subtract one and get value from different column

Tags: sql, oracle

Apologize for title. Having trouble explaining this.

I am running into an issue, and I am not sure what the best approach is here. Please see table picture. In this data set I need to find the date prd1 date in the prd2 column. If found, I need to then look at the dense_rnk column minus 1 and grab the value in the VAL column.

For example: 4/10 was found and the dense_rnk is 4 minus 1 is 3. The value needed in the output column is Z because it corresponds to dense_rnk 3. Should be driven by the dates on prd1.

Is there an excel offset comparable function that I can use in oracle? I added the window function thinking it would help, but it made everything more complicated.

Is this even possible? I appreciate any help here.

[image]

Comment: Since this sample data seems to be already a result of a query, could you please create a fiddle which includes the create table command, all insert commands and the query that procudes this result?

Comment: Is there always a 1-1 relationship between dense_rnk and Val? i.e. is it possible to have (dense_rnk, val) = (1,S) in one row and (1, Z) in another row? If yes, that's something you'll need to address first

Comment: Hello and thank you. There is no create table or insert. Just querying multiple tables. I cannot include the query due confidentiality however, the reason there are dups it is because there is a join to get prd2 and the Val value.

Comment: dense_rnk() comes from Over partition by ID and then ordered by prd2

Comment: @not_that_simple Of course you can. Replace `your_super_confidential_table1` with `table1` and `your_super_confidential_value1` with `1` etc. Also there's no need to include all the data, just 5-10 rows per table to demonstrate the issue. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a 2-step lookup, so

1. create 1st lookup (`dense_rnk`, `val`) in `cte_rnk_val`
2. create 2nd lookup (`id`, `prd2`, `rnk`) in `cte_prd2_rank`
3. join all three together to get output

```
with cte_rnk_val as (
select dense_rnk as rnk, val from tab_secret group by 1,2),
cte_prd2_rank as (
select id, prd2, dense_rnk-1 as rnk from tab_secret group by 1,2,3)
select s.id,
       s.prd1,
       s.prd2,
       s.dense_rnk,
       s.val,
       r.val as output
  from tab_secret s
  join cte_prd2_rank p
    on s.id = p.id and s.prd1 = p.prd2
  join cte_rnk_val r
    on p.rnk = r.rnk;
```

Output:

```
id  |prd1      |prd2      |dense_rnk|val|output|
----+----------+----------+---------+---+------+
7865|2015-04-10|2013-02-21|        1|S  |Z     |
7865|2013-07-09|2013-02-21|        1|S  |S     |
7865|2013-07-09|2013-02-21|        1|S  |S     |
7865|2015-04-10|2013-02-21|        1|S  |Z     |
7865|2015-04-10|2013-07-09|        2|Z  |Z     |
7865|2013-07-09|2013-07-09|        2|Z  |S     |
7865|2013-07-09|2014-10-10|        3|Z  |S     |
7865|2015-04-10|2014-10-10|        3|Z  |Z     |
7865|2015-04-10|2015-04-10|        4|Z  |Z     |
7865|2013-07-09|2015-04-10|        4|Z  |S     |
7865|2013-07-09|2016-10-15|        5|R  |S     |
7865|2015-04-10|2016-10-15|        5|R  |Z     |
7865|2015-04-10|2021-10-16|        6|R  |Z     |
7865|2013-07-09|2021-10-16|        6|R  |S     |
```

Query was tested in MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You might have to translate to Oracle, since this is formatted for SSMS.

```
SELECT e.Val
FROM (
    SELECT c.dense_rnk-1
    FROM (
        SELECT b.dense_rnk
        FROM data a INNER JOIN data b on a.prd1 = b.prd2 
    ) c
) d LEFT JOIN data e ON d.dense_rnk = e.dense_rnk
```

Do note that this solution is pretty awful. You'd probably be able to do better with the original tables rather than the provided result set.